# Union of closed sets in a metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, self-learning

There is an exercise that asks to show that:

> If a countable union of closed sets has nonempty interior  in a
>   complete metric space, then at least one set of the union has nonempty
>   interior.

Is this result valid? Doesn't the complete metric space that should be the countable union itself?

How could I prove it?

So far, I have the Baire theorem in hand:

Let $(E,d)$ be a complete metric space. Then every intersection of countably many dense open sets is dense.

Comment: It is preferable that countable means "finite or countably infinite" so that "uncountable"  means  "not countable". So your last sentence should say "Then the intersection of any non-empty countable family of dense open sets is dense."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the sets be $A_n$ and suppose they all have empty interior while the union does not. Then the complement of each, $A_n^c$, is dense. So by the Baire theorem, $\cap_nA_n^c$ is dense. But $\cap_nA_n^c=(\cup A_n)^c$, implying $\cup A_n$ has empty interior, a contradiction.

Comment: Oh very nice! thank you.

Answer (score 0):

We argue by contraction. We assume that all the closed set , say $F_n$, have no interior. Then we know $(F_n)^c$ is dense and open, hence by Baire category theorem, we get $\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^\infty (F_n)^c$ is dense, that is $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty F_n$ has empty interior, it’s a contraction.

Comment: How did you conclude that the union of closed sets has empty interior?

Comment: Ok, I already understood. You used  the fact that the closure of complement is the complement of interior